# Calculating averages based on adjustable, non-overlapping averaging period (4, 7, 30, 42 days) while aggregating (grouping) based multiple variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I’d like to apply a distinct (not rolling) seven day averaging period to a set of data, but the seven day window does not start until a sample is "found" and is not based on calendar weeks.

I’ve tried the following code but problem with this code is that it gives a rolling averaged sample for every sample in the data set.  Instead I need to aggregate all samples that appear within the averaging period into a single sample.

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)


Analyte<-c("Copper", "Copper", "Copper", "Copper", "Nickel", "Nickel", "Nickel")
Date<-mdy(c("1/1/2015", "1/3/2015", "1/12/2015", "1/15/2015", "1/3/2015", "1/6/2015", "1/8/2015"))
Matrix<-c("Water", "Water", "Water", "Water", "Water", "Water", "Water")
Fraction<-c("Total", "Total", "Total", "Total", "Dissolved", "Dissolved", "Dissolved")
Result<-c(0.6, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.1, 0.9, 1.0)
d<-cbind.data.frame(Analyte, Date, Matrix, Fraction, Result)


d$Date2<-d$Date
d$dateinterval<-interval(d$Date2-days(7), d$Date2+days(7))

d2<-ddply(d, c("Analyte", "Matrix", "Fraction"),function(df){
  SevenDayResultMean<-rep(NA, length(df$Date))
  SevenDayN<-rep(NA, length(df$Date))

  for(i in 1:length(df$Date)){
    SevenDayResultMean[i]<-mean(df$Result[df$Date2%within%df$dateinterval[i]], na.rm=T)
    SevenDayN[i]<-length(df$Result[df$Date2%within%df$dateinterval[i]])
  }
  return(data.frame(SevenDayResultMean=SevenDayResultMean, Date=as.character(df$Date), SevenDayN=SevenDayN))
}
)
```

The above code returns the table below which is a rolling average and not what I need.  In the table below, the first nickel sample is averaged with the following two nickel samples.  Then the second sample is averaged with the first and last sample, and so on.

```
Analyte     Matrix     Fraction    SevenDayResultMean   Date       SevenDayN        

Copper      Water      Total       0.45                 2015-01-01        2
Copper      Water      Total       0.3                  2015-01-03        2
Copper      Water      Total       0.55                 2015-01-12        2
Copper      Water      Total       0.6                  2015-01-15        2
Nickel      Water      Dissolved   0.67                 2015-01-03        3
Nickel      Water      Dissolved   0.95                 2015-01-06        3
Nickel      Water      Dissolved   1.0                  2015-01-08        3
```

Ideally, I would define an averaging period then group all other variables by like values.  I would need to get a table like the following:

```
Analyte    Date       Matrix     Fraction     Result

Copper     1/1/2015   Water      Total        0.45
Copper     1/12/2015  Water      Total        0.55
Nickel     1/3/2015   Water      Dissolved    0.67
```

Here, the first two samples were averaged because there were within seven days of the first sample, had the same fraction, matrix, and analyte and became the first entry in the result table.  The same for the next 2 samples of copper and all of the nickel samples were averaged for the same reasons.  The date applied to the sample in the result table doesn’t really matter as long as the date is within the seven day period that was averaged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `dplyr` we can do:

```r
library(dplyr)

d %>% 
  group_by(Analyte, Matrix, Fraction) %>% 
  mutate(interval = cumsum(Date - lag(Date, default = min(Date)) >= 7)) %>% 
  group_by(interval, add = TRUE) %>% 
  summarise(Date = min(Date), Result = mean(Result)) %>% 
  select(Analyte, Date, Matrix, Fraction, Result)

#> Source: local data frame [3 x 5]
#> Groups: Analyte, Matrix, Fraction [2]
#> 
#>   Analyte       Date Matrix  Fraction    Result
#>    <fctr>     <date> <fctr>    <fctr>     <dbl>
#> 1  Copper 2015-01-01  Water     Total 0.4500000
#> 2  Copper 2015-01-12  Water     Total 0.5500000
#> 3  Nickel 2015-01-03  Water Dissolved 0.6666667
```

Data:

```r
library(lubridate)

Analyte <- c("Copper", "Copper", "Copper", "Copper", "Nickel", "Nickel", "Nickel")
Date <- mdy(c("1/1/2015", "1/3/2015", "1/12/2015", "1/15/2015", "1/3/2015", "1/6/2015", "1/8/2015"))
Matrix <- c("Water", "Water", "Water", "Water", "Water", "Water", "Water")
Fraction <- c("Total", "Total", "Total", "Total", "Dissolved", "Dissolved", "Dissolved")
Result <- c(0.6, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.1, 0.9, 1.0)
d <- data.frame(Analyte, Date, Matrix, Fraction, Result)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  This was a great deal simper than I had imagined.  Just what I was looking for.  As the data I am working on is rarely in chronological order, an “arrange(Date)" was necessary as the first filter to order the dates prior to running the rest of the code.  Once that was in, it worked great.  

I do keep receiving an “Unknown column ‘colname’” or “Unknown or uninitialized column ‘colname’” error when I run everything in RStudio.  I have researched it and it looks harmless.  Does anyone know how to fix it other than turning off all warnings?

Thanks again!

Comment: This code alone shouldn't​produce any error or warnings. Maybe something before or after. Or maybe an outdated library. Hard to tell based on the showed example. Pls consider upvoting and accepting the answer if you find it useful :)